# Use two querysets in one for loop in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm building an inventory management app for an organisation in Django. This organisation has multiple rooms each with storage sections on shelves.

I'm trying to display the number of storage spaces free in each room plus the number of occupied storage spaces using one for loop. So far, I have managed to display this data but I have to use two separate for loops and two querysets, 'Vacant_location_data' and 'Occupied_location_data'. [image: See attached image for how this is currently displaying.]

I would like to be able to use a single for loop for this if possible as it will allow me to plot this data in a graph. Is this possible?

Below is a simplified version of my code:

My models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    loc_room = models.CharField()
    loc_section = models.IntegerField()
    loc_shelf = models.CharField()


class Box(models.Model):
    box_contents = models.CharField() 
    Location = models.OneToOneField()
```

My views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    Vacant_location_data = Location.objects.values('loc_room').filter(box__isnull=True).annotate(nempty=Count('id')).order_by('loc_room')
    Occupied_location_data = Location.objects.values('loc_room').filter(box__isnull=False).annotate(nempty=Count('id')).order_by('loc_room')
```

My HTML:

```
<div>

  {% for each_room in Vacant_location_data %}

      {
        <p>"Room name": "Room {{each_space.loc_room}}"</p>
        <p>"Free Space": {{ each_room.nempty }}</p>
      },

  {% endfor %}

</div>


<div>

  {% for each_room in Occupied_location_data %}
      {
        <p>"Room name": "Room {{each_room.loc_room}}"</p>
        <p>"Occupied Space": {{ each_room.nempty }}</p>
      },
  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: Django 1.11 the LTS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue with some help from an outside source. For anybody with a similar issue this is what I changed in the views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    Vacant_location_data = list(Location.objects.values('loc_room').filter(box__isnull=True).annotate(nempty=Count('id')).order_by('loc_room'))
    Occupied_location_data = list(Location.objects.values('loc_room').filter(box__isnull=False).annotate(nempty=Count('id')).order_by('loc_room'))

    for i, vacant in enumerate(Vacant_location_data):
        vacant['occupied'] = Occupied_location_data[i]['nempty']

return render(request, 'inventory_management_app/user_profile.html' ,
{"Vacant_location_data":Vacant_location_data,
"Occupied_location_data":Occupied_location_data,})
```

Now, with the HTML I could use a single for loop to display both occupied space alongside unoccupied space per room:

```
{% for each_space in Vacant_location_data %}
        {
            "name": "{{ each_space.loc_room }}",
            "id": "{{ each_space.loc_room }}",
            "data":

            [
                [
                    "Free space",
                    {{ each_space.nempty }}
                ],

                [
                    "Total Used Space",
                    {{ each_space.occupied }}
                ],


            ]
        },

        {% endfor %}
```